# Rails: Customize a form's label with a dynamic value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a label in my app like below.

```
<div class = "form-group">
  <%= form.label :shipping_destination,:class =>'col-sm-2'%>
</div>
```

Instead of showing "Shipping Destination", I want to set a dynamic value coming from Spree, which is

```
<%=@order.shipping_address.country.name %>
```

How do I pass this as a value to the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class = "form-group">
  <%= form.label :shipping_destination,@order.shipping_address.country.name,:class =>'col-sm-2'%>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Just pass the string as second argument to the label form helper to customize the label name

```
<%= form.label :shipping_destination,"My Custom Label",:class =>'col-sm-2'%>
```

Comment: What If I want to give the label any name?

Like Just destination without having to do the `shipping_destination` thing.

Comment: Lets say you have a field product `<%= f.label :product, 'Your Product' %>` must work without any issue. Did you check you are not missing anything